# Time Table with year/month/date and hour/minute/second

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to make a time table that includes all dates from 1/1/2024 to 12/31/2024, and on a separate column, or on the same one, have a count for all the hours (12:00:01, 12:00:02, etc). Whenever I try to make it, either one or the other fails. Right now I just have the following code:

```
TimeTable =   CALENDAR ( DATE(2024, 1, 1), DATE(2024, 12, 31) )
```

This gives me all the dates, if I could get help with the time part on this same table I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the table you created you can use GENERATESERIES with TIME(0,0,1) :

```
TimeTableUpdated = 
    GENERATESERIES(
        DATEVALUE(
            MIN(TimeTable[Date])
        ),
        DATEVALUE(
            MAX(TimeTable[Date])
        ),
        TIME(1,0,1)
    )
```

[image]